# mysql using sum and group by clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following code.The query woks well in mysql but it does not work when integrated with java.Please check the code.Sum is not  calculated correctly for all the columns.Please Help .Thanks a lot

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Sum11{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Sum of the specific column!");

        Connection con = null;
         int sum1=0;
         int sum2=0;
         int sum3=0;


        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prathi","root","mysql");
            try{
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT  Service_ID,SUM(consumer_feedback) FROM  consumer1 group by Service_ID");
                while (res.next()){
                    int data=res.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    int c1 = res.getInt(2);
                    sum1 = sum1+c1;
                }
                System.out.println("Sum of column "   +sum1);

                while (res.next()){
                    int data=res.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    int c2 = res.getInt(1);
                    sum2 = sum2+c2;
                }
                System.out.println("Sum of column "   +sum2);

                while (res.next()){
                    int data=res.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    int c3 = res.getInt(1);
                    sum3 = sum3+c3;              
                }
                System.out.println("Sum of column "   +sum3);
            }// end of try inner block
            catch (SQLException s){
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have my table as follows.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Service_ID | Service_Type | consumer_feedback |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|         31 | Printer      |                 1 |
|         32 | Printer      |                -1 |
|         32 | Printer      |                -1 |
|         32 | Printer      |                 0 |
|         33 | Printer      |                 1 |
|         33 | Printer      |                 1 |
|         31 | Printer      |                -1 |
|         31 | Printer      |                -1 |
```

Comment: *You really need to work on your code style/formatting.*   Specifically, develop consistant indentation, blank line & curly bracket usage.  It makes your code more readable by both you, and those you ask for help from.

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: A bunch of formatted code... what should you get?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing the SUM and GROUP by in MySQL, then doing it again in Java?  This code isn't even wrong.

Comment: Please. use the `edit` button, rather than posting twice the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 `while (res.next())` loops working on the same `ResultSet`.  However, the first `while` loop will iterate over all the rows, and the last 2 `while` loops won't do anything (because `res.next()` will be false at that point).

If you can explain why you have 3 loops and what you're trying to do, we can tell you what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but shouldn't the GROUP BY clause have a HAVING clause also?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if you would do the `SUM` twice, once in `SQL` and once in `Java`.

Your source is quite hard to read though.

Why do you have `while (res.next())` three times without initializing `res` in between?
Once it returns `false` in the first loop, it won't be true for the other loops...

If this does not help yet, please reformat your Java code.